Set snap options in Forge Viewer
I'd like to disable certain types of snapping in the viewer, such as vertices or midpoints.
Could you advise on how to do this?
The documentation for the Snapper class seems a bit unclear on this topic.
I've tried to create an new snapper but no succes.
Thank you all!

This is not officially supported, unfortunately, but if you like living on the edge, the Snapper class has a method called setSnapFilter(filterFunc) you can use to specify a custom filtering function. filterFunc must be a function that accepts a single argument of type SnapResult, and it should return a boolean value indicating whether the snap result argument is acceptable.
Here's a code snippet that'll make sure the snapper object used by the measure extension only accepts midpoints:
const SnapType = {
    SNAP_VERTEX: 0,
    SNAP_MIDPOINT: 1,
    SNAP_CIRCLE_CENTER: 2,
    SNAP_EDGE: 3,
    SNAP_FACE: 4,
    SNAP_CIRCULARARC: 5,
    SNAP_CURVEDEDGE: 6,
    SNAP_CURVEDFACE: 7,
    RASTER_PIXEL: 8,
    SNAP_INTERSECTION: 9
};
measureExt = viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.Measure');
measureExt.snapper.setSnapFilter((snapResult) => snapResult.geomType === SnapType.SNAP_MIDPOINT);

